# Is there any way to call a function by another function argument?

Tags: javascript, function

I have two JavaScript function. I want to call a function by another function argument.
Like this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Javascript Function</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function fOne()
        {
            alert("Function One");
        }
        function fTwo(f_name)
        {
            f_name; // I want to Call fOne() here
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="fTwo('fOne')">Call Function</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this posible in any way?

Comment: just replace f_name; with fOne();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function one() {
    alert('one');
}

function two(fname) {
    window[fname]();
}

two('one');
```

For a more complete answer, see here: [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Javascript Function</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function fOne()
        {
            alert("Function One");
        }
        function fTwo(f_name)
        {
            f_name(); // I want to Call fOne() here
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="fTwo(fOne)">Call Function</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is all that you need

Comment: Additionally, check out the "call" and "apply" methods -- they let you set the "this" object, and "apply" lets you pass an array to represent all the arguments (for when you don't know at code-time how many arguments there will be).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Javascript Function</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function fOne()
        {
            alert("Function One");
        }
        function fTwo(f_name)
        {
            f_name(); // I want to Call fOne() here
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="fTwo(fOne)">Call Function</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to pass a reference to your function (`fOne`) and not a string (other answers are already covering this). However, if you *really* want to call your function by its name, you can look it up in the `window` object:

```
function fOne(){ console.log("fOne"); }
function fCall (f_name) { 
    window[f_name]();
}

fCall("fOne"); // results in console.log.
```

However, stringly code tends to be more error prone, so use the method provided by Akshay or Rahul instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
function fTwo(f_name)
{
    eval(f_name+"()");
}
```

I'll let someone cleverer than I explain the security implications.

Comment: Evil!! Eaval is Evil!!

Comment: someone like @AkshayKhandelwal